# How to compare a subquery with a column in Laravel's query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I compare a subquery with a column in Laravel's query builder? `whereColumn` method only accepts string values for columns, `where` method on the other hand is not suitable, as it compares a column or a subquery against a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't the where method suitable? You can do

```php
DB::query()
    ->from('a_table')
    ->where('column_a', '=', function ($query) {
        $query->select('column_b')->from('some_other_table')->limit(1);
    });
```